Send email in dynamic actions
I have a question, I'm configuring my org for Salesforce mobile and I'm using dynamic actions and dynamic forms for the case record layouts, however, using dynamic actions I can't set the sending email as a "button" so that in the form without dynamics actions appears
Using dynamics actions:

Without dynamics actions:

